# How to prevent deletion or updation of other childs while updating only few from @OneToMany relation from parent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have class like below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private List<Child> childs;
```

i am trying to update few childs from parent but while updating Jpa updating null for remaing childs parent id. how do i prevent this effect and how to update only few childs with out modifying others.

Answer (score 0):

Just load set all `Child` references as they exist in the database.
Hibernate will notice they are unchanged and not update them.